# SD card reader gets a "Buffer I/O error on dev" several times when inserting a card. Why?

Tags: mount, usb-flash-drive, sd-card

I've just finished my new PC (OpenSuSE Leap 15.1) together with a multi-card reader (Icy Box IB-865) attached to the USB 3.0 header of the mainboard (Gigabyte A320M-H). It reads USB sticks perfectly, but when inserting an SD card (I've tried two such cards, which both did work in the old system and in the camera), the KDE device management dows not show up with a freshly mounted SD card. One of the LEDs on the device (the blue one) flashes fast, and the other one (amber) is flickering all the time. Mounting manually does work, but accessing the card sometimes works and sometimes not:

```sh
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /mnt/SDcard                            32 ↵
╭─jacek@epica /mnt/SDcard
╰─➤  ls -al
ls: Can't access 'DCIM': I/O error
ls: Can't access 'MISC': I/O error
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 32768  1 Jan 1970   .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    16 26 Jan 13:48  ..
d????????? ? ?    ?        ?             ? DCIM
d????????? ? ?    ?        ?             ? MISC
```

The syslog gives me a whole bunch of strange error messages:

```sh
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  dmesg | tail -35
[ 3268.836328] sd 10:0:0:2: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3268.836331] sd 10:0:0:2: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 dd 3f 80 00 00 08 00
[ 3268.836333] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 31276928
[ 3269.191523] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3269.587514] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3269.983561] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3270.379583] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3270.775622] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3271.167547] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3271.192898] sd 10:0:0:2: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3271.192905] sd 10:0:0:2: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 dd 3f 80 00 00 08 00
[ 3271.192908] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 31276928
[ 3271.192914] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 3908592, async page read
[ 3271.425263]  sdc: sdc1
[ 3271.563539] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3271.959719] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3272.355456] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3272.751517] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3273.151724] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3273.543463] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3273.568453] sd 10:0:0:2: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3273.568462] sd 10:0:0:2: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 dd 3f 80 00 00 08 00
[ 3273.568466] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 31276928
[ 3273.923497] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3274.319489] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3274.715482] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3275.115478] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3275.519479] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3275.915533] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3275.940787] sd 10:0:0:2: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3275.940796] sd 10:0:0:2: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 dd 3f 80 00 00 08 00
[ 3275.940799] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 31276928
[ 3275.940804] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 3909616, async page read
[ 3276.173370]  sdc: sdc1
[ 3276.311469] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

What's going on here? And: How do I get rid of such errors? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found out the culprit: It was unstable power fed by the onboard USB header! I attached the card reader to an add-on USB 3.0 PCIe card with its own internal header and power fed by the system's PSU directly —and suddenly, the card reader started working without any trouble!